# How to remove this pipe plug?

Tags: pipe

I'm trying to install my dishwhasher and I'm at the point where I need to install the drain hose.
However, the pipe is obstructed by this plug:

[image: plug]

I guess this is the right pipe (please confirm).
I tried to remove it with pliers and screwdriver with hammer without any success.
How may I remove it?
Thanks.

**Edit:** Here's another picture:
[image]

Comment: looks like some random hunk of plastic someone shoved in there. Answer more force..vice grips. If its really stuck try cutting the first barb off the tube with a hacksaw.

Comment: Not a big deal to replace it.

Comment: That plug may have been glued in.

Comment: If you do get it out, cut it or open the pipe, HOW do you intend to connect the dishwasher drain to it?  Dishwasher drains are not designed to connect to a pipe like that, they have a rubber fitting that fits over a barbed pipe that is on the air gap or the tail piece of the sink. This does not look like the "right pipe" to attach to if you want to be in compliance with code or use the drain hose that came with the dishwasher.

Comment: @Alaskaman I have a rubber tube.

Comment: @antoyo The additional photo is very helpful. Although the pipe is not the barbed one that is typically use it may be small enough, If the rubber end of your discharge tube will fit over it and you can secure well with a hose clamp. ( that is not to say that it meets code. ) You should be able to cut the plug  flush to top of the pipe and see if the opening size is sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a plug in a barbed fitting for hose with clamp attachment. When not being used, the drain is sealed by the plug.

I would apply heat to the barbed section causing it to expand slightly and loosen it's grip on the plug. A hair dryer might work, if not an electric heat gun set to LOW worked all the way around the barbed section for a few minutes then try turning it out again - and remember "righty-tighty, lefty-loosey".

Answer (score 2):

Considering the shape of that, I suspect it's intended to be cut off to get the size you want - if there was no dishwasher here before now, it may never have been cut open in the first place. The "stepped" section is my primary clue in making this guess.

As such, the "plug" may not be a plug, it may be molded in place. Difficult to tell for certain from this angle of picture.

Hmm. That may be an optical illusion and it's just a normal barbed fitting? If so, try sawing the plug off flush with the end. Then, if need be, drill the thing open.

Comment: I added another picture. Is it still what you think I should do? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Second picture looks threaded, so "use a bigger wrench" (or the suggested heat-gun and wrench) seems likely.